# Is interface merging limited to the current scope?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compile the following code using TypeScript compiler v3.5.3:

```
interface X {
    test1():void
}
var createX=function():X{
    var x:X=({} as X);
    x.test1=function(){return;} // raises error "Property 'test1' does not exist on type 'X'".
    interface X {
        test2():void
    }
    x.test2=function(){return;}
    return x; // raises error "Property 'test1' is missing in type 'X' but required in type 'X'"
};
```

The compile errors `Property 'test1' does not exist on type 'X'` indicate that  interface merging is limited to the current scope. When moving the definition of `test2` out of the `createX` function, the snippet compiles without errors:

```
interface X {
    test1():void
}
interface X {
    test2():void
}
var createX=function():X{
    var x:X=({} as X);
    x.test1=function(){return;}
    x.test2=function(){return;}
    return x;
};
```

Is interface merging limited to the scope the interface is defined in? If yes, is there a way to merge the scoped interface definition with the global one?

Comment: No. These declarations are lexically scoped like everything else declared within a function. What's the use case?

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Instead of writing a separate declaration file or putting all declarations and documentation at the top of the script, I'd like to add that right above the line where I start defining the respective function (makes it easier to maintain IMO). Since my script is returning a single creator function that has all functionalities encapsulated inside of it, I would have to write the declarations inside that creator function.

Comment: I see what you are saying but if that matters your file is probably too long and needs to be split up to make maintenance easier.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: You are probably right, but I thought there might be a workaround for the issue I described. PS: Could you please turn your response into a short answer so that I can mark this question as done? If no one else magically provides any solution, I wlll check it within ~24h. Thanks for your help.